# Hudson and build warnings: possible to exclude a project from reporting?

Tags: configuration, hudson, compiler-warnings, projects-and-solutions

I'd like Hudson to send an e-mail to developers whenever a warning is encountered in the build (VS2010, TFS)

The problem is that the solution contains several projects from another company that we cannot touch. Since they are part of the solution, they need to be built when the solution is built, but we don't want Hudson to count warnings from those projects (there are plenty of them).

Is there a way to tell Hudson not to care about warnings in those projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ${BUILD_LOG_REGEX} token of the email-ext plugin to filter the warnings in your projects.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to handle it is to make different projects out of them - build the 3rd party dependencies, then build the code you wrote.

Note also that there is a threshold on warnings that you can set.  So if you know how many warnings are in the 3rd party stuff you can set the limit one higher - that way you get an email indicating the new warning.

I think you can also set up an email/status to notify if there is an increase in number of warnings since last build.

Comment: That sounds good, thank you very much! However, I'm afraid it's no good for us, because the third party projects are still being developed. We cannot (and don't want to) build them separately. Also, the number of warnings can vary in those projects, so we cannot just set the limit of warnings as a constant number...

Comment: Why can't they be built separately?